# Can't replicate Codeception dependency injection example from docs

Tags: php, codeception

I'm following the example from http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Dependency-Injection

Currently I have this in my Cest:

```
/**
 * @var Helper\MyHelper
 */
protected $myHelper;

protected function _inject(\Helper\MyHelper $myHelper)
{
    $this->myHelper = $myHelper;
}
```

And generates the following error:

`Failed to inject dependencies in instance of 'HomeCest'. Failed to create instance of 'Helper\MyHelper'. Failed to create instance of 'Codeception\Lib\ModuleContainer'. Parameter 'config' must have default value.`

This is my Helper:

```
<?php
namespace Helper;

class MyHelper extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public function login($email, $password = '')
    {
        $I = $this->getModule('PhpBrowser');

        $I->fillField('email', $email);
        $I->fillField('password', $password);
        $I->click('Ok!');
    }
}
```

My goal is, if I can get this working, would be to create a `BaseCest` where I can inject all helpers, pageobjects and stepobjects.

The helper is properly loaded in `acceptance.suite.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was in previous version of Codeception: 
https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2230

Codeception versions from 2.1.2 should not have this bug.